# String not splitting every space?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split a string at every space so I can take a certain string out of it, using this code.

```
String[] array = input.split("\\s");
String output = array[1];
```

If the input is

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

the output would be something like

```
2 3 4 5
```

When all I want is the 2. Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Comment: that should work. is your input string exactly "1 2 3 4 5"?

Comment: Why splitting by "\\s" and not by " " ?

Comment: the input string is not actually 1 2 3 4 5, that's just an example of it. /m/UserName/s//w UserName2 this is an example message!/e/ is closer to what the actual string may be. When I do the array[0] in this case it would return UserName2 this is an example message!/e/

Comment: @Reimeus is it? I thought it was the same, with just a different string

Comment: @reimeus, okay, so how can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @YourNameHere so your are saying that you want only the string between ONLY spaces and not the other stuff? So not this "m/UserName/s//w" but only this "UserName2"??

Comment: @atomCode yeah, this is a packet the client is sending to the server, I use those slashes and other information to show what kind of message it is and such. I thought that if I were to split it by spaces, since the first one has no spaces, that would not matter. I just use the second object out of the array (array[1]) to try and grab jsut the UserName2, accept it returns  this is an example message!/e/ and when I do 2 it returns is an example message and so on. When I do array[0] it just returns the whole string starting from UserName2. I am trying to just remove UserName2 in the easiest way.

Answer (score 4):

```
    str = "1 2 3 4 5";
    String[] array = str.split("\\s");
    System.out.println(array[1]);
```

Comment: thats what I have, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "1 2 3 4 5";
//Regex is not really necessary in this simple case
String[] array = str.split(" ");
String output = array[1];
```

Comment: Quoting the question above: 
`When all I want is the 2. Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?`

Comment: @MilindGokhale Quoting the answer: "regexp is not really necessary in this simple case". It answers the "how can I avoid it" pretty well.

Comment: Right, unfortunately the question was not asked correctly to begin with.